# How to inject bean into BeanDefinitionParser?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a parser.

```
class MyAbstractBeanDefinitionParser extends AbstractBeanDefinitionParser {
    @Autowired
    private String playerName;
    // getters/setters
}
```

I want to inject into the parser a String (playerName). To do that I create a bean and wire it to the context.

```
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ctx.getBeanFactory();
beanFactory.registerSingleton("playerName", name);
```

When I create a `GenericXmlApplicationContext` it executes `BeanDefinitionParser` method 'parseInternal' but I don't see my dependency. Here is my question: how can I inject a playerName to `MyAbstractBeanDefinitionParser`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to inject a String value to `playerName` field. This can be easily done using the `@Value` annotation.

Like this:

```
class MyAbstractBeanDefinitionParser extends AbstractBeanDefinitionParser {
    @Value("The value String you want to inject")
    private String playerName;
}
```

In this example the playerName field will hold the value of:

The value String you want to inject

The only configuration you'll have to do, in order that the above will work, just add to your Bean XML Configuration file the line:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Comment: I create a context manually via `new GenericXmlApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have an XML configuration file in your project (for beans)?

Comment: No, I don't have it.

Comment: Then add XML bean configuration file and on it add the context namespace and the next line: <context:annotation-config/>   and load that xml configuration file using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

This is strictly using the **Spring XML bean configuration** thus eliminating the bean creation in the java code; Once your context is loaded spring will create the bean which is below:

```
<bean name = "MyAbstractBeanDefinitionParser" class="x.x.package.MyAbstractBeanDefinitionParser">
    <property name="playerName" value="YourString">
    </property>
</bean>
```